# Export PrimeNg Carousel as Pdf

Tags: angular, pdf-generation, primeng

I am using PrimeNg Carousel to show around 7 different treetable on a view.

Using jsPdf to print the current page as pdf but it will not export the item from carousel which are not being shown on screen.

So any leads on how implement such case for export where everything can be exported would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it a year ago, in one of my projects. I have used native implementation of JSPdf so that I can write whatever I want, it's not dependent on any DOM or UI view.

This is a clean and native approach based on JSPDF API, but its a bit lengthy task to map and draw each of text with x-y coordinates calculation, but it's really awesome and bug-free.

[check more info here](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/)